# How do you troubleshoot a website javascript popup that should be showing up on a dnn in order to get things connected from an external popup builder?

Tags: javascript, html, dotnetnuke

I'm currently working with a website created in DNN and I am trying to get a popup onto the home page---I am currently using Popupsmart for ease of use, but I have tried to install the javascript code and popupsmart is not recognizing that it is installed. I've tried two different ways of installing---via google tag manager and a content injection module.

It is a custom-designed popup to collect lead info on potential new customers (pretty standard).

I am attaching some images to go along with this post and would love any help in troubleshooting the issue. Thank you in advance!

I tried GTM and a content injection module and thought that this would fix the issue. Not sure where I'm going wrong.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

You have several possibilities.

If you use a Text/HTML module, you can add the script to the header or the footer, but if you do that often it can get a bit hard to maintain. And you don't have much control of where the script will appear in the rendered page.

I would suggest to use [Will Strohl's Content Injection Module](https://github.com/WillStrohl/dnnextensions/releases), that let's you inject anything on the page with much more control over it.

But if you want this on every page of your site adding it to the theme would be the best choice.

Comment: Michael, thank you so much! I really appreciate the insights. I will try this out and let you know if I can see any changes on my end!

Comment: Michael, I've been trying to figure this out with no luck. I recorded a short screen recording explaining the problem in more detail, so that you guys get a better understanding. If you could send over a quick screen recording of how you would potentially troubleshoot/solve it yourself that would be awesome!

Here's the link of me explaining things in more detail: https://share.vidyard.com/watch/qmdrJF11WAEFEsn6pqYzaW?

Or could you hop on a quick call? I am more than willing to pay to get this resolved asap!

Comment: Did you check if your browser is not blocking popups?

Answer (score 0):

Per page, header tip:

In the page settings for your home page, go to the **Advanced tab** > **SEO** > **Page Header Tags**. This section will inject HTML into the HEAD of that specific page. Since it is HTML for this input, be sure to wrap and javascript in  tags.